# Counter synchronization across two clock-domains

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I would like to understand different approaches to implement a cross clock-domain counter. In all of the following possibilities I have:

```
clk_a : in std_logic;
clk_b : in std_logic;
reset : in std_logic;

-- cross-domain counter
signal frm_cnt : standard_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
-- control signal: increment counter (synced to clk_a)
signal frm_cnt_inc : std_logic;
-- control signal: decrement counter (synced to clk_b)
signal frm_cnt_dec : std_logic;
-- control signal, perform action on the counter
signal frm_cnt_modif : std_logic;
```

The approaches I consider are:

Non-clocked counter similar to the answer in [How is this simple counter implemented on an FPGA without a clock?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/154329/how-is-this-simple-counter-implemented-on-an-fpga-without-a-clock)

```
frm_cnt_modif <= frm_cnt_inc or frm_cnt_dec; -- can also be xored

frame_counter : process(frm_cnt_modif, reset)
begin
  if reset = RST_ACTIVE then
    frm_cnt <= (others => '0');
  elsif rising_edge(frm_cnt_modif) then
    if frm_cnt_inc = '1' then
      frm_cnt <= incr_vec(frm_cnt);
    elsif frm_cnt_dec = '1' then
      frm_cnt <= decr_vec(frm_cnt);
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

This simulates fine, and Vivado is able to synthesize it, however it complains about using `frm_cnt_modif` as *clock*, which causes timing problems. Additionally the control signals have a chance of overlapping.

Another approach I have tried is to have separate counters in their respective clock domains and perform logic based on their difference. Here, I am concerned with counter overflow, so resetting them when no action on both sides is performed and they are equal seemed like a good solution, however I think that the signal controlling the reset will be subject to similar synchronization problems.

What I am experimenting right now is the 'synchronization to the faster clock'. I have a:

```
control_synchronizer : process(clk_b, reset)
begin
  if reset = RST_ACTIVE then
    frm_cnt_inc_sync <= '0';
  elsif rising_edge(clk_b) then
    if frm_cnt_inc_sync = '1' then
      frm_cnt_inc_sync <= '0';
    elsif frm_cnt_inc = '1' then
      frm_cnt_inc_sync <= '1';
    else
      frm_cnt_inc_sync <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

And the actual counter increment and decrement are performed in a process synchronized with `clk_b`. This seems to work fine as long as `clk_b > clk_a and clk_b < 2 * clk_a`.

Any other possible solutions and/or best practices? (I am aware that I should probably use grey-codes for the counter itself).

EDIT1:

After reply from Dave and reading http://fpgacenter.com/examples/basic/edge_detector.php I ended up with the following:

```
control_a : process(clk_a, reset)
begin
  if reset = RST_ACTIVE then
    frm_cnt_inc_d <= '0';
  elsif rising_edge(clk_a) then
    if frm_cnt_inc = '1' then
      frm_cnt_inc_d <= '1';
    else
      frm_cnt_inc_d <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

control_b : process(clk_b, reset)
begin
  if reset = RST_ACTIVE then
    frm_cnt_inc_sync <= '0';
    frm_cnt_inc_sync_d <= '0';
  elsif rising_edge(clk_b) then
    frm_cnt_inc_sync_d <= frm_cnt_inc_sync;
    -- this check was ensuring 1 to 1 pulse translation before rising edge detection
    --if frm_cnt_inc_sync = '1' then
      --frm_cnt_inc_sync <= '0';
    if frm_cnt_inc = '1' then
      frm_cnt_inc_sync <= '1';
    else
      frm_cnt_inc_sync <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

frm_cnt_inc_result <= not(frm_cnt_inc_sync_d) and frm_cnt_inc_sync;
```

This seems safe for any clock values. What I do not understand however, is the purpose of the `frm_cnt_inc_d` FF (code simulates perfectly fine without it). Anyone able to explain if it is indeed necessary?

Comment: It is necessary. If you don't yet understand the implications of [metastability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A11683+metastability), you are quickly going to get into trouble when designing for multiple clock domains. I suggest you read up on this topic before proceeding.

Comment: Now that I think about it I do remember hearing about that during one of my courses. Since this is actually the first time I am doing something cross-domain I completely forgot about that. The third FF in the code you have provided is also because of metastability problem, is that correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you by any chance counting video frames in a frame buffer? I do this sort of thing all the time.

One way to pass a pulse from one clock domain to another is to turn it into an edge and then do edge detection on it. In domain A, use the pulse to toggle a FF. In domain B, synchronize the output through two FFs. Run the output of the synchronizer through an edge detector (FF and XOR gate).

You'll get a pulse in domain B for every pulse in domain A, as long as the pulses don't occur faster than either clock.

---

This is needed often enough that I've created a generic module to implement it. `xd_` is short for "cross-domain" — I have other modules in this library that perform similar functions.

```
entity xd_pulse_xfer is
  generic (
    ACTIVE_RESET     : std_logic := '1';   -- active level of reset input
    ACTIVE_IN        : std_logic := '1';   -- active level of input pulse
    ACTIVE_OUT       : std_logic := '1'    -- active level of output pulse
  );
  port (
    reset            : in  std_logic;
    clk_a            : in  std_logic;
    pulse_in         : in  std_logic;
    clk_b            : in  std_logic;
    pulse_out        : out std_logic
  );
end xd_pulse_xfer;

architecture behavior of xd_pulse_xfer is
  signal toggle    : std_logic;
  signal toggle_a  : std_logic;
  signal toggle_b  : std_logic;
  signal toggle_c  : std_logic;
begin
  process (clk_a)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk_a) then
      if reset = ACTIVE_RESET then
        toggle <= '0';
      elsif pulse_in = ACTIVE_IN then
        toggle <= not toggle;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  process (clk_b)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk_b) then
      toggle_a <= toggle;        -- synchronizer
      toggle_b <= toggle_a;      -- synchronizer
      toggle_c <= toggle_b;      -- edge detector
    end if;
  end process;

  pulse_out <= (not ACTIVE_OUT) xor (toggle_b xor toggle_c);

end behavior;
```

Comment: Those are actually Ethernet frames, but yes, I am counting the amount of them in a buffer so I guess this would be very similar to your use case. If I understand you correctly (and I am still quite new at this) this will be similar to the third approach with `control_synchronizer` where `frm_cnt_inc` is a pulse from domain A. Is the second FF in A supposed to be reset after a confirmation signal from domain B?. `frm_cnt_inc_sync` will be the first FF in the B domain and I am supposed to add another one after? I will try to test this and edit my question with the code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: After comparing the code you have provided with the one I have written I want to ask the following: 1. Your implementation is separate component. Since I'm doing it in one entity, I think it is reasonable to use only one FF in domain A (see an edit to the question). 2. Why do you need 3 FF in domain B (wouldn't `toggle_a xor toggle_b` suffice)? 3. Does your approach of **ANY** edge detection has benefits over e.g. rising edge detection (apart from requiring only one xor gate instead of an inverter and AND gate)? Thank you for your time.

Comment: See my comment above about metastability. You REALLY need to understand this, and a behavioral simulation won't demonstrate it. It's a common pitfall for newbies. And don't be afraid to introduce sub-modules. You don't get any prizes for putting everything in one giant module, especially when you have a common function that can be debugged once and reused many, many times.

Comment: Just to explicitly answer my own question 3 about **ANY** edge detection: Apart from requiring only one XOR, using **ANY** edge detection and *toggle* signal allows handling of consecutive pulses to be transferred cross-domain.